# remove first occurrence of an element in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I'm trying to remove the first occurrence of an element from a list in Prolog.

My code:

```
remove_first_X(X,[X|Xs],Xs). %remove X
remove_first_X(X,[Y|Xs],[Y|Xs]) :-
   remove_first_X(X,Xs,Xs).
```

Doesn't work:

```
?- remove_first_X(1,[1,2,3],[2,3]).
true.

?- remove_first_X(1,[2,1,3],[2,3]).
false.
```

Please help! :-)

Another attempt is closer:

```
remove_first_X(X,[X|Xs],Xs).
remove_first_X(X,[Y|Xs],[Y|Ys]) :-
   remove_first_X(X,Xs,Ys).
```

But removes X after its first occurrence:

```
?- remove_first_X(1,X,[2,1,0]).
X = [1, 2, 1, 0] ;
X = [2, 1, 1, 0] ;
X = [2, 1, 1, 0] ;
X = [2, 1, 0, 1] ;
false.
```

Comment: By first occurrence, you mean the first term that's *equal* to the term you're searching for **OR** the first term that *unifies* with the term you're searching for? This clarification becomes relevant when the list contains *non-ground* terms and helps in selecting the best answer to the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the adding one thing to the second attempt

```
remove_first_X(X,[X|Xs],Xs).
remove_first_X(X,[Y|Xs],[Y|Ys]) :- 
    X \= Y,
    remove_first_X(X,Xs,Ys).
```

What happen in the example you ran was that

- For `X = [1, 2, 1, 0]` it simply tried the first clause of `remove_first_X`
- The next element was by going in the second clause and again to the first one, you can see that nothing prohibits that `X = Y`, that's something you should make sure of.

Comment: I was assuming too much pattern matching.. I should do some more reading. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

The implementation given by @chamini2 is *impure*, and can become *logically unsound when working with non-ground terms*. Consider the following two queries:

```
?- E=1, remove_first_X(E,Xs,[2,1,0]).
E = 1, Xs = [1,2,1,0] ;
E = 1, Xs = [2,1,1,0] ;
false.

?- remove_first_X(E,Xs,[2,1,0]), E=1.
E = 1, Xs = [1,2,1,0] ;
false.                                    % one solution is missing!
```

*[prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) to the rescue!*
By replacing `(\=)/2` with `dif/2`, the code gets **logically pure**:

```
remove_1st_x(X,[X|Xs],Xs).
remove_1st_x(X,[Y|Xs],[Y|Ys]) :- 
    dif(X,Y),
    remove_1st_x(X,Xs,Ys).
```

Let's run above queries again, this time with the improved implementation:

```
?- E=1, remove_1st_x(E,Xs,[2,1,0]).
E = 1, Xs = [1,2,1,0] ;
E = 1, Xs = [2,1,1,0] ;
false.

?- remove_1st_x(E,Xs,[2,1,0]), E=1.
E = 1, Xs = [1,2,1,0] ;
E = 1, Xs = [2,1,1,0] ;
false.
```

*That's better!* And the other queries given by the OP also work like they should:

```
?- remove_1st_x(1,[1,2,3],[2,3]).
true ;
false.

?- remove_1st_x(1,[2,1,3],[2,3]).
true ;
false.

?- remove_1st_x(1,X,[2,1,0]).
X = [1,2,1,0] ;
X = [2,1,1,0] ;
false.
```

---

#### Edit 2015-05-07

Above implementation of `remove_1st_x/3` leaves behind a useless choice-point when it could succeed deterministically.
Let's get rid of that inefficiency while preserving [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity)!

Using `if_/3` and reified equality `(=)/3` (a.k.a. `equal_truth/3`), as defined by [@false](https://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false) in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) to question "[Prolog union for A U B U C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358456/prolog-union-for-a-u-b-u-c)", we can define `remove_1st_x/3` like this:

```
remove_1st_x(E,[X|Xs],Ys) :-
   if_(X=E, Xs=Ys, (Ys=[X|Ys0],remove_1st_x(E,Xs,Ys0))).
```

Let's run above queries again! Note that all succeed deterministically.

```
?- remove_1st_x(1,[2,1,3],Ys).
Ys = [2,3].

?- remove_1st_x(1,[2,1,3],[2,3]).
true.

?- remove_1st_x(1,[1,2,3],[2,3]).
true.
```